# Which to use when - COCOS2d or simple UIImageView with animation?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am going to create simple iPad game, in which arrow going to hit balls. Where balls are moving in random direction with random speed. When arrow hits ball there is blast like animation with sound (Collision detection is main thing here). So for this what should i prefer. Should I use simple UIImageView and animation or use COCOS2D. Also I am new to COCOS 2d. Any other options are also appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use cocos2d Animation .Refer below link
if u have spritesheets try this:

1) http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

or u have separate images refer this:

2) http://cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:animation

Answer (score 0):

Using cocos2d has a lot od advantages over UIKit. One of the things is box2d which will be very helpful for game like this [at least I got this impression for your question].
Do some research about box2d collision detection.

Comment: Also, as stated by @banu there is the whole animation advantage. It's very easy and thanks to support for spritesheets memory handling is pretty good. I think you can't go wrong with Cocos2d in here. Whenever you need something from UIKit you can still use it [like menus, tabs etc], although cocos still allows you to create them on your own.